# Spring Framework: How and where use the "name" of the @PropertySource?

Tags: spring, spring-properties

In Spring Framework, for the `@PropertySource`, according with its API or javadoc it has the [name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html#name()) attribute

```
Indicate the name of this property source. 
If omitted, the factory() will generate a name based on the underlying resource 
(in the case of DefaultPropertySourceFactory: 
derived from the resource description through a 
corresponding name-less ResourcePropertySource constructor).
```

Ok, is clear that is possible define the name such as:

```
@PropertySource(name="infra", 
                value={"classpath:/com/.../infrastructure.properties"})
```

But How and where use that name? What is its purpose?

Comment: To identify which propertysource was used to retrieve a property value from when applying logging.